# Why is no reputation given upon selecting a best answer?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

On SO, you get 2 rep when you select a best answer. Why is there no such thing on Code Review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into your [reputation history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29985/alex-popov?tab=reputation), you will see that you were actually awared some “+2”s:

```
+2 on 2013-11-21 10:41 accept   Polynomial Equation solver
+2 on 2013-11-18 09:44 accept   Caesar Cipher
-2 on 2013-11-18 09:44 unaccept Caesar Cipher
+2 on 2013-11-13 22:50 accept   Caesar Cipher
```

It can take a while for the reward to appear.